# How can I turn off the fullscreen setting if I can't access the menu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I turned on fullscreen but Minecraft crashed and now it crashes every time I start it. Please tell me how to turn fullscreen off if I can't access the settings menu.

Comment: Have you looked at the settings, windowed mode can be changed there - or does it crash before you get there? Need a bit more info

Comment: Try alt-enter? For many programs it switches between fullscreen and windowed mode.

Answer (score 6):

Go into C:/Users/youruser/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/options.txt and set **fullscreen:** to *false*.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the .Minecraft folder and start up the game again, and let it download. remember to back-up all your saves (if you have any)

.Minecraft's default location on windows is: C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft

Comment: *\Roaming\.minecraft

Answer (score -1):

If you're on Windows press F11 if Function Lock is on. (If you have a F1-12 key that has a symbol, For Example: Volume mute, press it. If it does nothing then Function lock is off)

If Function lock is off, hold the FN key and press F11.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: This won't help since it crashes before you can press any buttons.